# Explain VBScript code

Tags: vbscript, serena

Can anyone help me understand what this piece of VBScript is doing. I get lost on the WhereClause bit

```
 If CVs = "," or CVs = ",," Then
    ExistingSupplierCVs = 0
Else
    Set CVRecords = Ext.CreateAppRecordList( ActivityTableId )
    WhereClause = Left(CVs, Len(CVs)-1)
    WhereClause = Right(WhereClause, Len(WhereClause)-1)
    WhereClause = "TS_ID in (" & WhereClause & ") and TS_SUPPLIER = " &      Supplier

    If Not CVRecords.ReadWithWhere( WhereClause ) then
        Call Ext.LogErrorMsg( "TeamScript Error : Cannot find " & QUOTE & WhereClause & QUOTE & " in table " & QUOTE & "USR_ACTIVITY" & QUOTE )
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ExistingSupplierCVs = CVRecords.Length()
End If
```

Comment: You attempt to explain it and I'll tell you if you were right.

Comment: WhereClause = from the left .. (return CVs, (length of CV's) -1)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Dave stated: They are removing the first and last characters from the `CVs` string.

A simpler approach would be to use `Mid`

`WhereClause = Mid(CVs, 2, Len(CVs) - 2)`

You could combine all three lines like this:

```
WhereClause = "TS_ID in (" & Mid(CVs, 2, Len(CVs) - 2) & ") and TS_SUPPLIER = " & Supplier
```

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is as below...

```
If CVs = "," or CVs = ",," Then
    ExistingSupplierCVs = 0 ' if the string is empty advise that the number of CVs is zero
Else
    Set CVRecords = Ext.CreateAppRecordList( ActivityTableId ) ' extract a list of CVRecords
    WhereClause = Left(CVs, Len(CVs)-1) ' strip the last char from this string
    WhereClause = Right(WhereClause, Len(WhereClause)-1) ' strip the first char from this string
    WhereClause = "TS_ID in (" & WhereClause & ") and TS_SUPPLIER = " &      Supplier ' insert the values into (presumably) a SQL query

    If Not CVRecords.ReadWithWhere( WhereClause ) then ' if executing the query returns false
        Call Ext.LogErrorMsg( "TeamScript Error : Cannot find " & QUOTE & WhereClause & QUOTE & " in table " & QUOTE & "USR_ACTIVITY" & QUOTE ) 'report an error and exit the subroutine.
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ExistingSupplierCVs = CVRecords.Length() ' return the number of records from the query
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very typical to the Serena Business Manager Composer language - AppScript.

The code which you have shared would be to count the number of records in a Multi Relation field and then enter the value in a field. A typical empty Multi Relational fields looks like this ",," and will values it will look something like this ",1,34," with the numbers showing the Ids of the field which this MR field is pointing to.

The where clause which is being built is nothing but simply removing the first and the last comma from the MR field and then query for the Ids.

let me know if you still have any doubts here.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is AppScript (the VBScript variant for SBM) you'll get better answers posting this to the [Serena (now part of MicroFocus) Community site](http://www.serenacentral.com/community/forums/categories/listings/sbm-business-management).